# RemoteControlClient image brightness?

Tags: android

I have the intention of allowing users to have pictures on their lock screen. The only way I could find do this easily is through a `RemoteControlClient`. My issue is the image is rather dim on the lock screen and I'm wondering if there is a setting to make it brighter. The code I set it up with is the following:

```
 private void setUpRemoteController() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioFocusListener(), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    ComponentName pareceiver = new ComponentName(this, PAReceiver.class.getName());
    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(pareceiver);
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(pareceiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0,mediaButtonIntent,0);
    remoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
    remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(
            RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    remoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
           RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS);
    audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
    Log.d("", "Started and set up controller and receiver");
}
```

On a related note: Is there any way to make the `RemoteControlClient` show up without hijacking the Audio Focus when I don't actually need it?